# Is there a way to specify requirements installation order in pip?

Tags: python, pip, ibm-cloud

I am troubleshooting an issue where some dependencies are not downloaded in the correct order and they fail. Below is the output I get when we try to build and deploy to Bluemix. Numpy is defined before but installs after scipy.

```
  Running setup.py install for blinker

     Running setup.py install for MongoKit

     Running setup.py install for Flask-Mail

     Running setup.py install for Flask-HTTPAuth

     Running setup.py install for passlib

     Running setup.py install for Werkzeug

     Running setup.py install for SQLAlchemy

     Running setup.py install for scipy

       Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-n4PVQ_/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8q5cRa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

       Traceback (most recent call last):

         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

         File "/tmp/pip-build-n4PVQ_/scipy/setup.py", line 237, in <module>

           setup_package()

         File "/tmp/pip-build-n4PVQ_/scipy/setup.py", line 225, in setup_package

           from numpy.distutils.core import setup

       ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core

       ----------------------------------------

       Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-n4PVQ_/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8q5cRa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-n4PVQ_/scipy
```

Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

Comment: Related: [How to specify install order for python pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394356/how-to-specify-install-order-for-python-pip)

Comment: Sounds like the setup for `scipy` is broken; your package should not be responsible for the dependencies of other packages.

Comment: Can you try to use this buildpack ? https://github.com/thenovices/heroku-buildpack-scipy , Reference : https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/162362/python-buildpack-for-scipy.html

Comment: https://github.com/ihuston/python-conda-buildpack may be a  better buildpack to work with numpy and spicy.