# "No module named numpy" error when installing from requirements.txt

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I am trying to install list of packages from `requirements.txt`. However, even though I have `numpy` listed in the file, package `tulipy` is returning error `ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`.
Please note, I still want to install the packages with one command, from file. Are there any workarounds for it?

*My `requirements.txt`*:

```
numpy>=1.14.1
Cython>=0.28.2
ccxt>=1.13.50
tulipy>=0.2.1
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the output from the pip installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Updated answer

`numpy` and `Cython` have to be installed prior to `tulipy`. To do this, you can install the packages in `requirements.txt` individually and in order. `numpy` and `Cython` *must* be above `tulipy` in the requirements file.

```
xargs -n1 pip install < requirements.txt
```

[taken from a [previous stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503666/5666087)]

## Old answer

`tulipy` requires `numpy` to be installed. To work around this, first install numpy, and then install your `requirements.txt` file.

```
pip install numpy
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

As proof that `tulipy` requires `numpy` during installation, please take a look at [`tulipy`'s `setup.py` file](https://github.com/cirla/tulipy/blob/edd6819f2571d3f58d04593d5429abcbca7df964/setup.py#L4).

Comment: So that meas the only solution is to run `pip install numpy` and then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`? Because if so, I will write a bash script to do it, since I want to install everything with one command.

Comment: @DJ_Tth3jtr - it seems that `pip` on its own cannot install numpy before tulipy. Please seem my edit. Something like that could be written in a bash script, but it is a one-liner.