# How is install order determined in `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Doing a `pip install -r requirements.txt` does not follow the order the modules are listed.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394356/how-to-specify-install-order-for-python-pip) points out how to do it.

I want to know how the order is determined by `pip`, and if the order is predictable in any way?

Comment: It follows package dependency. If package a in line 1 requires package x, then it will add package x which in turn may require package d.

Comment: @alvits Ah, I see.  Looks like it is creating a dependency tree first and then starting at the leaves.  It also looks like it installs git packages first.  Any other rules you are aware of?

Comment: So if PIP is mentioned in the requirements.txt file, it will get installed 1st?