# Wheel installation from within requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-wheel, python-venv

I'm trying to configure my `requirements.txt` which is the following:

```
wheel
apache-airflow
```

I created `python3.8 -m venv ~/test-env` and tried to do the installation. The problem is

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

produces tons of messages

```
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'                                                                                                                                                                                            

----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                        
Failed building wheel for thrift
```

I made sure that `wheel` is installed when doing `requirements.txt` installation:

```
Collecting wheel (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))                                                                                                                                                                              
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/83/b4a77d044e78ad1a45610eb88f745be2fd2c6d658f9798a15e384b7d57c9/wheel-0.33.6-py2.py3-none-any.
```

But if I install it separately

```
python -m pip install wheel
python -m pip install -r requirements
```

it works fine and the `python -m pip -r requirements` finishes with no error messages.

So isn't it possible to put `wheel` installation into `requirements.txt`? What is the proper way to deal with it when installing into `venv`? To install it before `requirements.txt` installation?

Comment: If you look at the `wheel` package you'll see this: "This library is the reference implementation of the Python wheel packaging standard, as defined in PEP 427." Theres no real point in installing it.

Comment: @SitiSchu In the official documentation guide it was mentioned to make sure the latest version `setuptools` and `wheel` via `pip`. https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#generating-distribution-archives

Comment: Thats the documentation for packaging a project, not installing a package.

Comment: @SitiSchu Without installing `wheel` package `bdist_wheel` command is not available for `setup.py`. That's exactly what I saw in the error messages. Why did you say that it was pointless?

Comment: As explained in the link you shared it's a requirement when building your own distribution package to upload them on pypi, not a requirment when installing your package elsewhere (i.e. no point to include it in requirements.txt)

Comment: @buran So how to explain this error message when installing from `venv` (installing in the core python installation works fine)?

Comment: Do you get a error when you run `python -m pip install apache-airflow` ?

Comment: @SitiSchu Yes, but only when installing into my own `venv` that I created specifically for that. Installation into the core system python works fine.

Comment: What is the version of _pip_ that is installed in your virtual environment?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this happens with older versions of *pip*. For example in my quick tests it happens with *pip 9.0.1* which is delivered by default with *Python 3.6*'s *ensurepip* standard library, but doesn't happen once *pip* is updated to *19.2.3* which as far as I know should be bundled with *Python 3.8*. You seem to be using Python 3.8 so I'm confused by the fact that you encounter this error. Anyway this error, shouldn't effectively block the actual installation of the requirements.

If possible I'd recommend updating pip:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

before installing the requirements:

`python -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt`

Installing *wheel* (or updating *pip*) from within the requirements file is not useful in this case.

Comment: What about when you have a package that requires a wheel be built during installation? If wheel is gathered and the package installed before wheel it doesn't work.

Comment: @ingyhere I do not understand what you mean. -- This is a rather old Q&A. Things have changed since then.

Comment: I mean exactly that you cannot install wheel to be used for something else within the same requirements file. It doesn't work in version 21.1.x (latest as of this writing). Pip must install wheel separately, in advance, of installing the requirements file. [Here's a kludgy workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202283/325452). Since this question is from 2019 I consider it relatively new as of 2021.

Comment: My guess, you probably want to disable pip's "build isolation". Look it up and see if that helps your use case.