# How to make 'pip install -r requirements.tx' to install one successfully then to the next to prevent all failing?

Tags: pip

if just using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It will download-all first then start to install one by one,if any package installation failed,I must download all again,so how to make it to download-install one by one,not download-all then install-all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify install order for python pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394356/how-to-specify-install-order-for-python-pip)

Comment: Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202283/7976758

Comment: You can also separate downloading and installing phases. First download packages with dependencies: `pip download -r requirements.txt -t download/dir`, then install with `pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --filnd-links=download/dir`