# Get versions of a .txt list of packages using pip.main

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pip

I'm trying to iterate over a list of packages in a text file to get the version of each package. The list in the pkgs.txt file appears like this:

```
{
"package1",
"package2",
...
}
```

Here is my most recent code:

```
with open("pkgs.txt", "r") as pkgs:
    for line in pkgs:
        version = subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'search', line])

with open("versions.txt", "w+") as versions:
    for ver in version:
        version.write(ver)
```

The error I'm getting is: `CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/conda/bin/python', '-m', 'pip, 'search', '{\n']' returned non-zero exit status 23.`

Could the issue be that I first need to remove the quotation marks and commas before I can loop through this list?

Comment: There is no `pip.main`, [_pip_ doesn't have an _API_](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program), one should do something like `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'search', line])`.

Comment: pip.main seems to work when I type in a package name manually. I'm just trying to find out how to get the names from an existing file instead.

Comment: I see you might have an older version of _pip_ where `pip.main` still existed. The advice still stands, no matter what version of _pip_ you have. -- For the rest, I haven't looked closely, seems quite straightforward. What are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: Thank you, I've tried the subprocess code but I'm getting an error 'returned non-zero exit status 23'. Perhaps there is something wrong with my code but I'm not sure as I'm still quite new to python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify install order for python pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394356/how-to-specify-install-order-for-python-pip)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+packages+one+by+one

Comment: Not quite, but thank you for the suggestion. I'll look through the other posts in the tag

Comment: You haven't clarified which part is giving you trouble? Is it about reading a text file? Reading line by line? What are you stuck on? Which parts do you have under control? You have to give details about what you did, what you saw, what your current status is, etc. Does the code in the question show the current state of your research?

Comment: That's a much better question now after the edits, it's much easier to help you. I upvoted the question. Question about the input file: Is it a specific format? It doesn't seem to be JSON, CSV, or anything I can identify.

Comment: Thank you for your edits and upvote. It's a list in a text file (sorry, I don't have much knowledge beyond that). It's the output from a previous subprocess command that used wget to get the list of packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(There are too many aspects in this question to cover it all at once. I will try to cover the initial points here, the rest should be asked in a new question.)

First, *pip* doesn't have an *API*. The preferred way of using *pip* from your own program is to call it directly as a *subprocess*.

The input format is nothing recognizable (not CSV, JSON, maybe YAML could cover it). But coincidentally the input format is somewhat readable as a literal Python list of strings, so one could try parsing the content with `ast.literal_eval`.

`pkgs.txt`:

```
{
"package1",
"package2",
}
```

`main.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ast
import pathlib
import subprocess
import sys

def main():
    file_name = 'pkgs.txt'
    file_path = pathlib.Path(file_name)
    file_content = file_path.read_text()
    pkgs = ast.literal_eval(file_content)
    print("pkgs", pkgs)
    for pkg in pkgs:
        print("pkg", pkg)
        command = [
            sys.executable,
            '-m',
            'pip',
            'search',
            pkg,
        ]
        print("command", command)
        command_output = subprocess.check_output(command)
        print("command_output")
        print('"""')
        print(command_output.decode())
        print('"""')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Extracting the correct information out of `command_result` could be treated in a follow up question. (I suspect calling `pip search` is not the best choice here, it might be worth going with one of [*PyPI*'s *APIs*](https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/api-reference/#available-apis) directly instead.)

```
command_output
"""
package2 (0.0.0)                      - 
101703383-python-package2 (0.0.3)     - This is my second package in python.
Vigenere-cipher-package2 (0.5)        - An example of Vigenere cipher
WuFeiLiuGuang-first-package2 (2.0.0)  - test pkg ignore

"""
```

---

**References**:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/11138259
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll try it out. And apologies as this may be a basic question but what do I do with main.py? Do I need to create this file?

Comment: Yes, create a `main.py` file in the same directory as `pkgs.txt` and run `python3 main.py`.