# is there a way to install a specific package at last from requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394356/how-to-specify-install-order-for-python-pip) seems there is no way to specify an order to install packages from `requirements.txt`. My scenario is a bit different so I just want to make sure if there is any way to do it right in the `requirements.txt` file.
I have multiple python packages in my `requirements.txt` that I install them from pypi repo. There is only one package that install it from a private repo and I'm able to do that using `--extra-index-url` option. Is there a way to instruct pip to install the public packages first using `--index-url` and then install the private package using the `extra-index-url`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If the private package depends on some PyPI packages, declare that in your `setup.py` and let pip figure it out.

Comment: Unless the installation process itself requires the presence of certain packages, the order in which they are installed shouldn't matter.